# Ruby .where to see if array includes a result that doesn't match query.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to query an array of signups. Each `Signup` has a field on it `twitter`.

The field is an array and at present will only have two items, but can also only have one. The three possible outputs from calling `Signup.twitter` are:

`Signup.twitter => ["No Twitter", "randomhandle"]`

`Signup.twitter => ["No Twitter"]`

`Signup.twitter => ["randomhandle"]`

I'm trying to use a .where query to only return me handles that have a `randomhandle` in. If they return `["No Twitter", "randomhandle"]` I still want that record to be returned though.

Any help must appreciated,

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
only_twitter_users = Signup.all.reject do |signup|
  signup.twitter == ["No Twitter"]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Try array search methods, like find_all (`select` is the same) or reject (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all)

Absolutely agree with the previous answer, but I would do it in 'positive' way, rather than 'negative' so as to keep it clear:

```
Signup.all.find_all do |signup|
  # Use Array.wrap or protect it from `undefined method for nil class`
  "randomhandle".in? Array.wrap(signup.twitter)
end
```

Ultimately, you can do whatever you want.

In case if the `twitter` field is association you can use `where` directly:

```
Signup.where(twitter: Twitter.where(name: "randomhandle"))
```

Check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html